# python Flask: query an item using GET

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to query one of the stock instead of all from the database. However, I only manage to get all that in the MySQL database but unable to get just one of them.

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='ppp.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='john',passwd='pw',db='vinus$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

@app.route('/KL', methods=['GET'])
def KLSE():
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE")
        a = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': a})

@app.route('/KL/<Stock>', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEstock():
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE")
        c = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    #return "hihi"
    return jsonify({'Stock': c})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It shows internal server error 500 to query a Stock. Example, I want to get a stock 'BINTAI' only. How can I work with my code?

```
{
  "Stock": [
    {
      "Previous_close": 0.09,
      "index": 0,
      "Vindex": 3.9,
      "Name": "PERISAI PETROLEUM TEKNOLOGI BHD [S]",
      "SELL_total": 52,
      "50d": "B1",
      "Momentum": "B",
      "BUY_total": 52,
      "Trade": "BUY",
      "SMA": "H3",
      "HOLD_total": 853,
      "52w": "H",
      "Change_pc": "20.000",
      "Market_sentiment": "Neutral",
      "Time": "2016/12/29 08:28:59",
      "Trend_date": "2016-12-28",
      "SMAcross": "H",
      "id": 1,
      "Change": "0.015",
      "Stock": "PERISAI"
    },
    {
      "Previous_close": 0.215,
      "index": 1,
      "Vindex": 3.26,
      "Name": "BINTAI KINDEN CORPORATION BERHAD",
      "SELL_total": 52,
      "50d": "B1",
      "Momentum": "B",
      "BUY_total": 52,
      "Trade": "BUY",
      "SMA": "H3",
      "HOLD_total": 853,
      "52w": "H",
      "Change_pc": "4.878",
      "Market_sentiment": "Neutral",
      "Time": "2016/12/29 08:28:59",
      "Trend_date": "2016-12-23",
      "SMAcross": "H",
      "id": 2,
      "Change": "0.010",
      "Stock": "BINTAI"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the stock name to the query as follows:

```
@app.route('/KL/<Stock>', methods=['GET'])
def KLSEstock(Stock):
    curs = db.cursor()
    try:
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock='%s'"%Stock)
    ...
    return jsonify({'Stock': c})
```

and one more thing when you pass an parameter to the url your view function has to take it too.

Comment: when I go to /KL/BINTAI, it still shows 500 internal server error

Comment: We forget to add `'%s'`

Comment: thanks. It works. I try on GET 'id', by replacing all the term Stock to id, as well as %s to %d and %f, but it does not work.

Comment: You have to specify value type like this `@app.route('/KL/<int:id', ...)`